# Why istream::rdbuf() append new line symbol "\n" even if the input file is just one line string in C++?

Tags: c++11, istream

Suppose a file "a.txt" which contains just one line string as below:

```
hello world
```

I don't contain any new line symbol like "\n".

```
void loadFileStr(istream& stream, stringstream& strs){
     str << stream.rdbuf();
}
```

I call loadFileStr and output its read string.

```
int main(){
    stringstream strs;
    ifstream ifs("a.txt",strs);
    loadFileStr(ifs, strs)
    ifs.close();
    std::cout << strs.str(); 
}
```

However,

```
strs.str()
```

shows hello world with newline.

```
hello world
'\n'
```

(\n) is just a space actually.

Is this rdbuf() feature or how can i read this file without any "\n"?

Comment: You might have pressed Enter after inputting the line, creating a newline character. Try creating the txt file programatically and see what it does

Comment: Actually i did created it by vim without no enter or "\n". I will make it programatically !

Comment: @EyalK. Thank you very much!! It works correctly, In the end this is a vim issue...

Comment: Text editing programs do a lot of things you wouldn't expect. Glad to hear it worked out